# Laravel: Check if record exists else

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a form in Laravel

```
{{ Form::label('address', trans('Address')) }} 
            @if ( $bounty->address == "NULL")
            {{ Form::text('address', Input::old('address'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            @else
            {{ Form::text('address', $bounty->address, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            @endif
```

This is the controller

```
public function bounty($id)
{   
    $title = $this->title->byId($id);
    $bounty = array();
    $bounty = DB::table('bounties')
        ->where('title-id', $id)
        ->first();

        return View::make('Titles.EditBounty')->withTitle($title)->withBounty($bounty);
```

Basically if there is already a value in the bounty table for the `address` field I want the form to set that value as the default value, else if should just return blank.

However, I keep receiving this error

Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/stephenm/public_html/app/views/Titles/EditBounty.blade.php)

```
<?php echo Form::text('address', Input::old('address'), array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
```

When there is no value in the `address` field

Comment: `Input::old()` won't give that error. Are you sure you're not getting it when calling `$bounty->address` ? That's more likely

Comment: how do I tell laravel blade to use input:old if there is nothing in the bounty->address field?

Comment: you could try `if(object_get($bounty, 'address'))`

Comment: yes that works thanks!  ill tick your answer if you post one

Comment: You could also avoid the `if`, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`object_get()`](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#arrays) helper function:

```
 @if(!object_get($bounty,'address'))
   {{ Form::text('address', Input::old('address'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
 @else
  {{ Form::text('address', $bounty->address, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
 @endif
```

Or even eliminate the `if` condition altogether, using `Input::old()` default value:

```
{{ Form::text('address', Input::old('address', object_get($bounty,'address')), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```